# "To get emotionally attached" VS "To be dependent"

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, expressions

I think "to be dependent on someone" can mean "to be emotionally attached / tied to that person." 
Though, I guess "to be dependent on someone" seems to cover a wider range of dependancies (like financial facets, emotional aspects, etc.) however I think freely interchange these two when it comes to emotional attachments. 
Let me illustrate my intention by an example.
I am wondering whether in the context below we can substitute "don't get emotionally attached to him too much" for the bold part:

> "Don't **get too dependent on** him, Draco," Pansy warned. "I don't want you to be devastated... [[Source]](https://m.fanfiction.net/s/9859162/1/A-Strange-Sort-of-Fluff)

I hope I have been able to make myself understood.

Comment: You can be emotionally attached and not be dependent....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In that context, yes.  However, the issue is that they overlap, not that emotional attachment is a subset of dependency.

Being hurt, or even devastated, because of the emotional relationship would be attachment.  However, dependency is something more.  Hermione and Harry were emotionally attached to Rob in *Deathly Hallows*, but they were not dependent on him -- when he left, they were capable to cope and carry on.